# Site Design Updates

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the DBA community site got a slight design update today. We have moved the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally in the future. Also we've updated the graphics to SVG for retina support. Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old CSS bugs. If you see any new ones, or old ones not being fixed, please let us know!

Comment: Is the loss of the background rectangles on main deliberate? It's still there on meta...

Comment: Hmmm, seems it's there on IE but not Firefox - maybe some caching issue on my browser?

Comment: Can you tell me which browser you're using and if you've tried refreshing recently. The background shouldn't have changed, and I'm seeing it.

Comment: I'm on FF35 and I tried a refresh and a private browser session

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you give up in the end or is it still on your list?